# Windows command prompt quickly disappears when running pip related commands

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, python

I installed Python 3.8.10 on my work desktop, and I need to install some packages using pip.

When I run the line that is supposed to install these packages, nothing happened, so to test if pip was working I typed in `pip -h`. The output I would expect from this command appears in another command prompt window for a split second and then quickly disappears. I typed in another command unrelated to pip (just checked my current directory), and the output appeared in the same window as it normally would.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Picture of the window that pops up and disappears after a split second when using pip -h

[image: Picture of the window that pops up and disappears after a split second when using pip -h]

Comment: If you wish to keep the command window open at termination, run cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

Comment: For a window to stay open you have to open it directly and then run the command in it. If a process opens the command window, when that process ends the window will disappear.